# Prove that $\mathscr{F}$ is $\|.\|_\infty$-dense in $C[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, approximation

Let $\{t_0,t_1,...,t_n\}\subset [a,b]$ and $\mathscr{F}=\{q\in\mathscr{P}:q'(t_0)=q'(t_1)=...=q'(t_n)=0\}$, where $\mathscr{P}$ is the set of polynomials.
Prove that $\mathscr{F}$ is $\|.\|_\infty$-dense in $C[a,b]$.

My try:

I have to prove that $\forall p\in C[a,b]$, $p\in \mathscr{F}$ or $p\in \text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n\in\mathscr{F}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $p\in C[a,b]$. Stone-Weierstrass theorem tell us that $\exists$ a polynomial $q^*$ such that $\forall t\in\{t_0, t_1, ...,t_n\}$, we have $|p(t)-q^*(t)|<\epsilon$. Then $p\in\mathscr{F}$.

Any suggestions to prove $p\in \text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n\in\mathscr{F} \forall, n\in \mathbb{N}$ would be great!

Answer (score 4):

According to the general Stone-Weierstraß theorem you only have to show that $\mathscr{F}$ contains the constant functions (trivial), is an subalgebra (easy to check) and that it separates points, i.e. for every $x \neq y \in [a,b]$ there is some $p\in \mathscr{F}$ such that $p(x) \neq p(y)$. I think some interpolation theorem could help there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry but I don't understand very well how those proofs are related with the Stone-Weierstraß theorem. And what operations are needed to prove in order to show that $\mathscr{F}$ is a subalgebra?

Comment: @SofíaContreras . "$\mathscr F$ is an algebra" (& hence a subalgebra of $C[0,1]$)  just means that $rf+sg$ and $fg$ are in $\mathscr F$ whenever $f,g\in \mathscr F$ and $r,s\in \Bbb R.$ (Where $(rf+sg)(x)=rf(x)+sg(x)$ and $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)\;)$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what kind of interpolation theorem could it be, all I could came up with were Theorems that lead to the conclusion $p(x)=p(y)$ How can I get the inequality?

Comment: @Jules_99 think of how to ensure that $p(x)$ has zero derivative in the $n$ given points. How much freedom do you have left?